# Load Balancer for NodeJS Net Server

Tags: node.js

I have a following `NodeJS` server file that is supposed to handle following `JSON` Message:

1. If received `message` as key, send some response.
2. If received `app` as key, send some `DLL` to the client.

Now I am interested in handling multiple clients that will, for this case, send only message as `Key` in JSON.

Here is the code:

```
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
  console.log('client connected');
  c.on('end', function() {
    console.log('client disconnected');
  });
  c.on('data', function(data) {

    var json = JSON.parse(data.toString());
    if(json.heartbeat){
      if(json.first_fetch === "1"){
        c.write("{\"config_changed\":\"true\",\"config\":\"This is some config\"}"); // JSON Message here
      }
      else{
        c.write("{\"config_changed\":\"false\"}");
      }
    }
    else if(json.message){
        c.write("{\"success\":\"true\"}");
    }
    else if(json.app){
      fs.exists('apps/'+ json.app + ".dll", function (exists) {
        util.debug(exists ? "it's there" : "Its not there");
      });
      var stats = fs.statSync('apps/'+ json.app + ".dll")
      var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"]
      var message = json.app + "\n" + fileSizeInBytes + "\n";
      c.write(message);
      fs.open('apps/'+ json.app + ".dll","r", function(status, fd){
        console.log(fd);
        var read_bytes = 0;
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('apps/'+ json.app + ".dll");
        fileStream.on('data',function(chunk){
          c.write(chunk);

        });
      })

    }
    else
    {
        c.write("{\"some\":\"error\"}");
    }
  });

  c.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  });

  // c.pipe(c);
});
server.listen(1936, function() { //'listening' listener
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

My client will send message as `{"message":"This is message"}`, and server will send `{"success":"true"}`. I received following benchmark of the server I created:

1. One client sent 200000 message in 7 seconds.
2. Two clients, each sent message in 13/14 seconds.
3. Three clients, each sent message in 17/17/16 seconds.

The time for each client reduces significantly when they are sending message to one server. I tried to run multiple server at once, but it gave:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1156:14)
    at listen (net.js:1182:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1267:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\nodeserver\server.js:54:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

If I want to get the performance of `200K in 7 seconds` for each of clients, how am I to proceed. I want to run multiple instance of servers, with a load balancer to improve the server efficiency. I am using Windows.

Comment: Why not use nginx as TCP loadbalancer : https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/

Answer (score 0):

try to use node.js Cluster module for this
https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

different nodejs instances can't share same port

another approach is to use external load balancer, `nginx` for example

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

Comment: I used the `cluster` library and it was still slower. I placed all my server logic in place of `http.createServer` template given. The statistics were nearly same with cluster too.

Comment: Cluster can add meaningful perfomance only if you had multicore / multithreaded cpu. Running clusten on 1 core / 1 thread CPU only decrease your perfomance. May be you try to use nginx as load balancer with node.js instances, running on different ports?

Comment: The machine has 4 core and yet using cluster is slow too

Comment: some sort of optimizations you can find here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880051/node-js-performance-optimization-involving-http-calls

Comment: node.js can be optimized in many ways, but you need to do it on server with some logic. Optimize of sending static message useless, nginx or other web servers do it easier. Popular approach - using nginx as static content handler and proxy to node.js for backend jobs